# Adding elements to *args list and passing the result further

Tags: python, variadic-functions

I'd like to have the following construction in my code:

```py
def target_function(*args, key=value, key2=value2, key3=value3, key4=value4):
    print(*args)

def function_prepending_arguments(*args, key4=value4):
    target_function(["a", "b", "c"] + *args, key4=key4)  # does not work, *args is a tuple
```

For `function_prepending_arguments(["c", "d", "e"], key4="dummy")` I expect to see `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` in my output.

How do I achieve this (in a most pythonic way, if possible)?

Comment: `target_function(["a", "b", "c"], *args)` ?

Comment: or `target_function(*["a", "b", "c"], *args)` -- not sure which you want

Comment: Probably `target_function("a", "b", "c", *args, key=key)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands added more detailed example

Comment: @GoodDok don't think it changes the solution really- why don't you show an example of your desired output for some inputs where `target_function()` includes `print(args, key)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands added an example what I meant by prepending arguments

Comment: well L3viathan's solution works then

Comment: @Chris_Rands frankly saying this did not work for me since 'b' was resolved as the second positional argument, I edited the question in order to show the more specific example although the answer to the question has been found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you can't concatenate list and tuple. So, just pass `('a', 'b', 'c') + args`. Or `['a', 'b', 'c'] + list(args)`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, `['a', 'b', 'c'] + list(args)` created a nested structure, but I was able to get rid of it [by using `list(*args)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58165136/9145106)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was

```py
def function_prepending_arguments(*args, key=value):
    target_function(['a', 'b', 'c'] + list(*args), key=key)
```

Thanks to [blue_note](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3208297/blue-note) for pushing me to the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be

```
x = [1,2,3]
# y = tuple/generator/list
y = (4,5,6)
x.extend(y) # won't return anything.
```